# Ruby on rails display objects in a box table with columns and rows populated dynamically

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have a model class `Student` which `belongs_to` two other models (`standard` and `house`)

Now the `Student` object can be uniquely identified by the `category_id` from the the other models it belongs to.

I wanted to show students in the view.With categories from Standard model to be the x axis(rows) and the categories from the house model to be the Y axis.(columns). Kind of a matrix representation.

Also the standards and houses changes from school to school. So they need to be populated from the db.

Is there some gem I can use to simplify the process.

I am a backend developer and have limited knowledge of Jquery and JS.

Edit: I just want a kind of a data grid with defined columns and rows. And the link to the object of a class is defined in the particular box.
For ex: In the box 1 defined by row 1 and column 1 there are three students. Box 2 defined by row 2 and column 1 has 2 students etc.(Kind of a matrix representation)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this matrix kind of thing previously, and I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774577/matrix-edit-in-rails-activeadmin). It's about active_admin, but the idea is the same.

I think for the problem you're facing, the easiest way is to build this matrix table yourself. Here's an example, and I use [Slim syntax](http://slim-lang.com/)

- the row header be the category
- the column header be the level

and then do something like below:

```
table
  thead
    tr
      - @categories.each do |c|
        td = c.name
  tbody
    - @levels.each do |l|
      tr
        td.column-header l.name
        - @categories.each do |c|
          - intersect_students = l.students.where(category: c)
          - if intersect_students.empty?
            td
          - else
            td = intersect_students.plunk(:name).join(', ')
```

NOTE: the finding of intersect is a bit slow.. needs some pre-processing logic to improve it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This looks like a good solution. However I am following an approach in which I define the table structure in the view first then filling it with data using ajax json response from a custom action. Will soon be posting this way of implementing this :)